# Emergency Sound Generation

Tags: audio, stm32, stm32f4

I have design an amplifier and microphane system for vehicles. I want to add emergency sounds like police, ambulance fire, etc. and air horn , normal horn. But actually i dont have any exprience about generate sound with stm microcontroller. I controlled other things on board with stm32f0. Does anybody could help me to how can i genarate these sounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For generating specific sounds for example police siren you need to know the **frequency** of it and then implement the same using PWM of STM32.

Comment: It is way but most of the time you need to  change PWM frequency and duty cycle for  a siren. As I remember  for a simple fire horn, we need to this operation 50-60 times. It is not a good practise.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I understand that point. I have to find frequency function. I still search it but i couldnt find. Maybe i tried with wrong key words. I guess that emergency sounds have a standard or regulation from goverments but  i couldnt find it. If you know that could you please share with me. I will code it as your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use DAC output of the STM32 processor. I have did two projects like for an police car and fire truck.

There is two point here. The first point is frequency density. Some sounds can have high frequency density and it can become big in the size for that reason, I suggest the use uSD card.

In the one of the project, I would go with internal memory and it could not enough. Just use DAC output of the stm32 use uSD card slot.

There is one more hint here, if you have a sample device to hear the sound. You can clone the signals on the DAC and you can directly use it your CPU DAC signals. It is the easiest way of doing this problem with that way you do not need analyze the signal. Tt is a way of doing this but, I would not recommended that way.

Comment: How can you find sounds frequency function? Or are you just play .waw or similar formats?

Comment: You can search with "sound to frequency converter".